# Pretty print xml & xsd in Java, BUT without any content change

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I found a lot of similar questions here, but my major purpose is NOT TO CHANGE the content!!! I just want to indent and adapt blanks, but do not want to change the order or anything else inside the xml / xsd files.

I found a solution in shell:
find . -name "*.xml" -type f -exec xmllint --output '{}' --format '{}' \;
find . -name "*.xsd" -type f -exec xmllint --output '{}' --format '{}' \;​

But why is this not possible in Java?

Comment: What leads you to believe it’s not possible?  What do you think [OutputKeys.INDENT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#INDENT) is for?

Comment: because I tried for myself ... it is adding some attributes like standalone or prearranging the order of some attribut.

Comment: You can control the standalone with OutputKeys.STANDALONE, but I don’t think the order of attributes can be preserved during transformation, probably because the XML document has the same meaning regardless of attribute order.